# How can I extend the FindObjectsByTag to filter multiple parents of the found objects?

Tags: unity, c#

```
private List<GameObject> FindDoors(string[] parents)
    {
        GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft);
        GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorRight);

        List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();

        List<GameObject> toRemove = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < allDoors.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < parents.Length; x++)
            {
                if (allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != parents[x])
                {
                    toRemove.Add(allDoors[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var it in toRemove)
        {
            allDoors.Remove(it);
        }

        foreach (GameObject door in allDoors)
        {
            Debug.Log("Door Parent : " + door.transform.parent);
        }

        return allDoors;
    }
```

Usage :

```
var allDoors = FindDoors(new string[]{ "Wall_Door_Long_01", "Wall_Door_Long_02" });
```

But in the function FindDoors the return allDoors is empty.
I think the problem is at this IF :

```
if (allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != parents[x])
```

Once it's Wall_Door_Long_01 so if it's Wall_Door_Long_01 it will not remove the item but next it's Wall_Door_Long_02 so now the it's true and will remove the even if the parent name is Wall_Door_Long_01 and same if it's Wall_Door_Long_02

And then in the end it will remove all the items.
But I want it to remove only doors that the parents of them is not Wall_Door_Long_01 and not Wall_Door_Long_02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match all criteria you must check for all conditions before removing.

```
bool match = true;
for (int x = 0; x < parents.Length; x++){
  match &= allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != parents[x];
}
if(match){
  toRemove.Add(allDoors[i]);
}
```